# Trying to call a macro (from VBA) using VSTO and having that Macro write data onto active workbook

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to call a macro from VBA using VSTO, and once the Macro is written, I am trying to write the data from the macro onto the active workbook. So far I can call the macro, but the macro will not write any data onto the active workbook. Does anyone mind having a look?

This is my C# code:

```
   public partial class Ribbon1
{
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void callVBA_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Workbook engrWorkbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
        var ActiveSheet = engrWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
        String FilenamePath;

        FilenamePath = "C:\Test\MyWorkbook.xlsm"; //Where the workbooks where all the marco are stored

        //~~> Start Excel and open the workbook.

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilenamePath,0, true); 
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        ActiveSheet.Activate();

        xlApp.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow;
        //~~> Run the macros by supplying the necessary arguments
        xlApp.Run("Test");
       

    }
}
```

My Macro is written here:

```html
Sub Test()
MsgBox ("hello")
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Game"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, stupid question but you're running "Test" when the macro name is "Print_to_PDF1", is that a typo on your behalf?

Comment: Yes its a typo. Ill fix it.